# Classes inside object literals

Tags: javascript, oop

I was just not sure how to search this out despite many tries, so forgive me if this has been answered before.

The question is simple: can I create an instance of class `window.A.class()` as `window.B`?

To clarify, I have an object literal holding all my data for a browser game:

```js
var gameName = {
  environment: function() {
    this.place = "...";
    // ...
    // ...
  },
  game: function() {
    this.player = function() {
       // ...
    }
  }
  // and so on...
}
```

Could I create a `window`-level `gameName.environment()` instance with `var A = new gameName.environment()`? Are there any restrictions to creating an object-bound class's instance outside the class' parent object?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/32LnS/

Comment: Just as a note -- javascript's object model is fundamentally different from a class-based model. Crockford http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html and others have argued (persuasively I think) that it's actually quite a bit more interesting/powerful than "classical" object models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter in this case how/where a function is *defined*. Consider these two examples:

```
function Foo() {}

var obj = {
    bar: Foo
};
```

and

```
var obj = {
    bar: function () { }
};
```

As far as the function and the object are concerned, those two examples are equivalent. So no, there is no problem calling a function assigned to an object property with `new`. All you need is a reference to the function, it doesn't matter how you get that reference.

You could do

```
var Environment = gameName.environment;
var A = new Environment();
```

if you like that better, but that's totally unnecessary.